# Is there a multitouch limit on Windows 8 tablets?

Tags: windows-8, tablet, multi-touch

I'm interested to know if there is any limitation about multitouch on Windows 8 tablets.

What I need to know is if it can handle more than 5 simultaneous touches at a time.

Comment: Yes. There are lots of 10-finger touchscreens out there http://www.slashgear.com/vizio-adds-10-finger-multitouch-to-all-in-one-pcs-for-windows-8-11251401/

Comment: You don't have to worry much about having more than 10 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/multitouch-hardware-reqs.

> For example, touchscreens that support fewer than five simultaneous
>   touch points don't work with certain features and apps that are part
>   of Windows 8 and Windows 8.1.

Windows requires five touch points it self so certified hardware should be good to go, you'll have to look up the touch specifications of the hardware itself.